# [pic] Possible to style a text with CSS?

Tags: html, css, photoshop

Preparing for a meeting with our designer later today, I was looking through his Photoshop sketches and wonder whether the following one could be expressed in HTML/CSS, without the need to render the text in Photoshop:

[image: Example text with glossy effects]

Do you think the color gradient and the drop shadow could be done 70-90% similar to the original within **plain HTML and CSS**, too?

Ideally even older browsers should at least be able to draw the text in a readable manner.

I found [this one back from 2008](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css-gradient-text-effect), maybe there is a more modern way of doing it nowadays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create your own FONT and embed that on the page.

See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220236/how-to-embed-fonts-in-html

However unless you need the text to be dynamic I would just recommend using a image. It will look better and be guaranteed to looked identical on all browsers

Answer (score 2):

You could use CSS3 gradients and drop-shadows for that desired effect, older browsers would just display a block colour, which would be fine.

It would load much quicker than an image as well as being easier to edit, it would be the right thing to do.